# Force HTML page to reload if updated recently

Tags: html, webbrowser-control

Is there a way that I can force a page to reload, but only if it has been updated recently?  I am working on a photography website so there are a lot of images, therefore it is best if it is cached.

However, if the content has been updated (e.g. more photographs added) then I want the browser to load a fresh copy, if not then use the version in the cache?

I was hoping that there was a meta tag that would take care of it.  I've read about the expires tag but that wouldn't help as the page isn't updated regularly.

I'm only using CSS, HTML and Javascript, nothing server side. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: I wonder how you manage your photos without a server side language? Do you update the HTML pages manually? Just curious :)

Comment: Felix - I just update them manually.  It's a side project for my girlfriend and not frequently updated so I just do an update.  I keep planning to automate it but it's hard to find the time!

Comment: How many images of which size or on this page that you consider a refresh being bad? Do you have a slow connection or do you have to pay for traffic? If there are so much images I would categorize them and every category gets its own page.

Comment: Images are split into 4 categories already. The largest category has 27 images. Per image 1 thumbnail (~17KB) is loaded plus 1 large image (~60KB) so I wouldn't want them loaded EVERY time.  Traffic isn't an issue, I have 10GB per month on my current plan and connection speed doesn't seem to be an issue. You can see the page at http://www.lesleywilliamson.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best would be to use HTTP caching mechanisms. If you can’t use server side languages to send appropriate HTTP headers, try a built in solution like [Apache’s mod_expire module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html). With that you can set a maximum age based on the request time:

```
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 week"
```

Comment: I don't know when a page will expire because there are no regular updates, it's as and when there are new photos to add. For example, if I set a page to expire 1 month after I add it but don't update it for 2 months then the browser will unnecessarily take a fresh copy for the second month, or am I misunderstanding how this would work?

Comment: @Fermin: The expiration affects only resources that are cached. An expired resource in a cache should not be used. Instead the resource should be requested again (either for revalidation or refetch). So in your case it doesn’t matter if you don’t know when a resource is expired. A low lifetime is just to ensure that the resource is requested often enough. A maximum age of one week means that your clients will only use variants that are not older than one week. And if you only set a low expiration for your HTML document, then only that documents will be requested that often and not the images.

Comment: So, to clarify the HTML source will be requested upon expiration but any images cached will be fetched from the cache?  Excellent, thanks for clarifying that Gumbo.

Comment: @Fermin: If you set the expiration for the images far in the future, they will not be refetched until then.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `ETag`.

> HTTP 1.1 introduced a new kind of
>   validator called the ETag. ETags are
>   unique identifiers that are generated
>   by the server and changed every time
>   the representation does. Because the
>   server controls how the ETag is
>   generated, caches can be surer that if
>   the ETag matches when they make a
>   If-None-Match request, the
>   representation really is the same.

Excellent information about caching can be found [here](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/).